# How to disable conversion of 0/1 to true/false in jackson 2.9.x

Tags: java, json, jackson, jackson2

I have a project that needs a strict json policy.

Example:

```
public class Foo {
    private boolean test;

    ... setters/getters ...
}
```

Following json should work:

```
{
    test: true
}
```

And following should fail (throw exception):

```
{
    test: 1
}
```

same for:

```
{
    test: "1"
}
```

Basically I want the deserialization to fail if someone provides something different than `true` or `false`. Unfortunately jackson treats `1` as true and `0` as `false`. I couldn't find a deserialization feature that disables that strange behavior.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can disable `MapperFeature.ALLOW_COERCION_OF_SCALARS`
From [docs](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.9.pr3/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/MapperFeature.html#ALLOW_COERCION_OF_SCALARS)

> Feature that determines whether coercions from secondary
>   representations are allowed for simple non-textual scalar types:
>   numbers and booleans.

If you also want it to work for `null`, enable `DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_NULL_FOR_PRIMITIVES` ([More Info](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/1106))

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

//prevent any type as boolean
mapper.disable(MapperFeature.ALLOW_COERCION_OF_SCALARS);

// prevent null as false 
// mapper.enable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_NULL_FOR_PRIMITIVES);

System.out.println(mapper.readValue("{\"test\": true}", Foo.class));
System.out.println(mapper.readValue( "{\"test\": 1}", Foo.class));
```

Result:

```
 Foo{test=true} 

 Exception in thread "main"
 com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot
 coerce Number (1) for type `boolean` (enable
 `MapperFeature.ALLOW_COERCION_OF_SCALARS` to allow)  at [Source:
 (String)"{"test": 1}"; line: 1, column: 10] (through reference chain:
 Main2$Foo["test"])
```

Comment: Note that there's a bug whereby this feature is ignored if you've enabled afterburner: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-modules-base/issues/69